# Implementing IEnumerable interface to my class

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I have this class, wherein I want to implement IEnumerable to be able to use foreach().
Here is my code by i think i'm not doing it correctly

```
public class SearchResult : IEnumerable<SearchResult>
{

    string Name { get; set; }
    int Rating { get; set; }

    public IEnumerator<SearchResult> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return( this );
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't really make sense for `SearchResult` to implement `IEnumerable<SearchResult>` - a single result isn't a sequence of results. Do you have some special reason to want to make a single result look like a single-element sequence?

Comment: Instead of IEnumerable<SearchResult>, how should it be declared? The only relevant concern for me is to be able to implement IEnumerable interface to the SearchResult class.

Comment: The point is that it's weird to want to use foreach over a single item. *Why* are you trying to implement this interface?

Comment: This makes... 0 sense.

Answer (score 4):

You could do:

```
public IEnumerator<SearchResult> GetEnumerator()
{
    yield return this;
}
```

However it's unusual for an object like this to implement `IEnumerable<T>` and return itself in a single-element sequence.

You might want to create a utility method instead:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> ToSequence<T>(T instance)
{
    reutrn new[] { instance };
}
```

Comment: I especially like the array variant. yield return is being overused for these simple cases where a list (of any kind) would have been enough, clearer and faster.

Answer (score 0):

If you really truly swear that you need to do this:

```
SearchResult justOne = ... blah ...;
foreach (SearchResult eachOne in justOne) {
   ... blah ...
}
```

Then you could do this minor modification to your method (use yield return instead of return):

```
public IEnumerator<SearchResult> GetEnumerator()
{
    yield return( this );
}
```